# Android: Share option menu open automatically while app run first time

Tags: android, menu

I am making drawing app. In my have i put the facility to share the drawing image. my problem is when i start my app first time share menu will open automatically without clickin on the menu button. I want to  open when i click on the menu button.

Here is my code for menu.xml

```
         <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Following is a code for java file.

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){


    Bitmap bitmap = drawView.getDrawingCache();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png";

    System.out.println("path="+path);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
    //Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
    return sharingIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

comment this line

Comment: hey do you have any idea for my second question?