# Android: How to share image with Share Option menu>

Tags: android, canvas, share

I am making a drawing app. Now i want to share my Drawing with share option menu. But drawing canvas image is not attaching while sharing.

```
         <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Following is a code of java file

```
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){


    Bitmap bitmap = drawView.getDrawingCache();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png";
    File file = new File(path+"/image.png");
    System.out.println("path="+path);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
    //Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
    return sharingIntent;
}
```

Please provide me the way to share canvas image with different apps. Thank you

Comment: What is different here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801499/android-share-option-menu-open-automatically-while-app-run-first-time

Comment: if you read it in detail you will understand

Comment: its because when you create share intent it take file at start up .

Comment: You have a bitmap. And a filename. Then you try to share a file with that name. Great chance that the file does not even exist. But the main point is that nothing connects your bitmap with a file(name). You forgot to save the bitmap to file first. To save it as image.png

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late reply. But this may help someone. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
  private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){

    // Save image to external storage before sending. With out saving, I to got a blank screen as attachment.
    String imagePath=saveToExternalSorage(mBitmap);
    File f=new File(imagePath);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

    //Create an intent to send any type of image
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
    return sharingIntent;
}
```

where

```
public String saveToExternalSorage(Bitmap b){
    // Get path to External Storage         
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/"+IMAGE_PATH);
    myDir.mkdirs();

    // Generating a random number to save as image name
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
    String fname = "Image_"+timeStamp+"_"+ n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Tell your media scanner to refresh/scan for new images
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                   System.out.println(path);
                }
            });
    return file.getAbsolutePath();

}
```

I wonder, saving the image before is the only way to share properly.